# Setting "Content-Security-Policy default-src https:" breaks site

Tags: nginx, http-headers, content-security-policy

I need to set the `Content-Security-Policy` header to allow loading scripts from any HTTPS source. When I add the following line to my `nginx` configuration, the look and feel of the site breaks. What am I missing?

```
add_header Content-Security-Policy "default-src https:";
```

I also tried adding a `*` at the end of `https` like this but this did not work as well,

```
add_header Content-Security-Policy "default-src https:*";
```

Comment: Use developer tools in a browser to verify that you're not loading any content over plain http.